# how to open a .pdf file in a panel or iframe using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to open a .pdf file on a button click. I want to open a .pdf file into a panel or some iframe. With the following code i can only open .pdf file in a separate window or in a save as mode.

```
string filepath = Server.MapPath("News.pdf");
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filepath);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();            
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + file.Name); 
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());            
        Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(file.Extension.ToLower());            
        Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
        Response.End();
    }
```

how to assign a iframe to the below line

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + file.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I can't answer your question directly (never heard of specifying a frame using a response header.)

What if, instead, you set the src of your iFrame to the page/url that writes the PDF to the client.  That way the server only cares about sending back the data and the client is choosing where to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Code formated for the below

```
private void ReadPdfFile()
{
    string path = @"D:\Hemanth\sample.pdf";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);
    if (buffer != null)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In .aspx page

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnPDFViewer" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnPDFViewer_Click" ToolTip="View PDF Document" CssClass="btn btn-white btn-sm"><span class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></span></asp:LinkButton>
 <asp:Button ID="btnDocShow" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" />
        <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeDocViewer" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlDocViewer" TargetControlID="btnDocShow"
            CancelControlID="btnDocClose" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlDocViewer" runat="server" CssClass="ibox" Style="display: none;">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <h5>Employee Doc Viewer</h5>
                <div class="ibox-tools">
                    <a class="close-link">
                        <i id="btnDocClose" class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <iframe src="#" id="iframePDFViewer" width="800" height="500"  runat="server"></iframe>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

In the respective server side code

```
protected void lnkBtnPDFViewer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + myfile.pdf;
        iframePDFViewer.Src = filePath;
        mpeDocViewer.Show();
    }
```

This will open the PDF file in a modal popup using iFrame.

Reference: [Code Project: Asp .Net PDF Viewer](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/827313/How-Can-I-Display-A-Pdf-File-In-A-Panel-In-Asp-Net)